# How to install older version of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I follow [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/) tutorial. He uses Tensorflow 1.10.0. I should use that version too. Because tutorial is not compatible with newer versions of Tensorflow.

So,when I open Anaconda Prompt and write

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

to base and I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9WbE.jpg) long error message. How can install Tensorflow 1.10.0?

I also tried:

```
conda create --name="tfold" python=3.7
conda activate tfold
pip install tensorflow==1.10.0
```

and I see this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.10.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.10.0
```

EDIT:  The oldest version compatible with Python 3.7 is 1.13. I installed Python 3.6. Then, I installed it using conda `create -n test_env tensorflow=1.10.0`

Comment: If you're using Conda, why would you install the package using pip?

Comment: I am a newbie. I didn't know that they conflict.

Comment: Try `conda create -n test_env tensorflow=1.10.0`.

Comment: `tensorflow==1.10.0` is not compiled for Python 3.7, the oldest version compatible with Python 3.7 is 1.13. Either install 1.13, or use Python 3.6 or earlier.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is because you are using python3.7

Try using pip and not pip3

Set python=2.7 and use pip install tensorflow==1.10, it worked fine for me.

Comment: I see error when I use pip instead of pip3. Tutorial says I should use newer versions than 3.6

Comment: The best solution is to completely change Python versions?